# Using custom tslint rule results in no implementation found

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint

I'm having difficulty to understand why my custom typescript rule is not working. 
Below some code to show my setup.

**package.json:**

```
 {
  "name": "lintingrules",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Custom linting rules",
  "main": "lintrules.json"
 }
```

**lintrules.json:**

```
{
    "rulesDirectory": "./rules",
    "rules": {
        "enounderscore": true
    }
}
```

**tslint.json of the project I want to use the linting rules:**

```
{
  "extends": ["lintingrules"]
}
```

In my folder `src/rules` I have one rule that uses `tsquery`. When using this in my angular project I always get the following message when running `ng lint`:

> Could not find implementations for the following rules specified in
>   the configuration:
>       enounderscore Try upgrading TSLint and/or ensuring that you have all necessary custom rules installed. If TSLint was recently upgraded,
>   you may have old rules configured which need to be cleaned up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So my mistake was that I didn't use the convention that TSLint needs but just created a file with a random name:

> Important conventions:
>
> Rule identifiers are always kebab-cased. Rule files are always
>   camel-cased (camelCasedRule.ts). Rule files must contain the suffix
>   Rule. The exported class must always be named Rule and extend from
>   Lint.Rules.AbstractRule.